# derivative of a function with disconnected domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

$f:A\cup E\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be differentiable, where $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\frac{1}{2}<x^2+y^2<1\}$$ and $$E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2<\frac{1}{2}$$ which of the following are necessarily correct?

$1.$ If $(Df)(x,y)=0\forall (x,y)\in A\cup E$ Then $f$ is constant.

$2$. If $(Df)(x,y)=0\forall (x,y)\in A$ Then $f$ is constant on $A$

$3$. If $(Df)(x,y)=0\forall (x,y)\in E$ Then $f$ is constant on $E$

$4$.If $(Df)(x,y)=0\forall (x,y)\in A\cup E$, Then forsome $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1)\in\mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)\forall (x,y)\in A,$ and $f(x,y)=(x_1,y_1)\forall (x,y)\in E$

So far I have dealt with derivative of a function, its domain was connected open or closed, So I have no  idea how to dealt with derivative of a function whose domain is disconnected. But as my intuition goes faster than my knowledge so I guess $2,3,4$ are correct. help me to find counter examples and reasoning if I am wrong

Comment: The derivative will be zero everywhere if and only if the function is *locally constant*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function on a connected set is locally constant if and only if it is constant.